# How do I extract the video:url value from this object?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

```
{

   "video:url" : "https://www.youtube.com/embed/oPVte6aMprI"
}
```

I am using vuejs, and I am going use the video in an iframe so it will much more helpful if there is any way to get the value using the key on `v-bind` or `:src` attribute. Or any other way in js

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you include the code you have already tried ? You are saying you are using VueJs, so there is a component you want to use this in ? Please do share !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference it with brackets:
If the name of the object is "obj", and you want the url value in const "value":

```
const value = obj["video:url"]
```